# Error creating a WCF endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

Why do I need to include a DnsEndpointIdentity when creating my WCF endpoints?

So when I create an endPoint like this:

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
```

I get a SSPI authentication failed error

But when I do this it works just fine:

```
DnsEndpointIdentity endpointIdentity = new DnsEndpointIdentity("sadmienjfkf");
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(uri, endpointIdentity);
```

Notice that I don't even need a specific value in the constructor, and leaving it blank works fine too.
Also note that in my Service endPoint definition I don't specify the servicePrincipalName, i.e. I don't include

```
<identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value="" />   
</identity>
```

I've been reading about DnsEndpointIdentity  and servicePrincipalName put i don't really understand.
Can anyone shine some light?

Answer (score 0):

What's your setup?

- What bindings are you using?
- Server config - what security is enabled? What other options are turned on?
- Client config - what security is enabled?

Maybe [this article here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122071525/http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2009/04/23/setting-up-wcf-to-impersonate-client-credentials.aspx) can explain more what the servicePrincipalName info tries to do?

Marc

Comment: security mode="Message"; clientCredentialType="Windows"; NetTcp Binding; Hosting in a console app on a different server

Comment: are you doing anything with impersonation?